# RSS for Future Items

Tags: rss

This may be a simple question, but for some reason I don't know this answer. Is it possible to create an RSS feed file that contains contents for an entire year but only publishes the current date and previous date information?

I have a client that wants to do a "this day in history" post. Currently, I am using IFTTT, and created around sixty dated posts for the next two months. Of course, this works -- but it is very labor intensive.

Is it possible to create an RSS feed that you could put all 365 days of data in to, but if someone pulls up the feed it only shows today's item and prior days in the feed?

Or is RSS not the proper technology to do this? The reason I am using RSS is for ease of use, and IFTTT will take those RSS feeds and pump it in to Facebook and Twitter for automatic status updates for my client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing

1. Using the Drupal backend of my website, I created a content type specifically for these posts.
2. I created individual articles for each day, and used the schedule module to schedule the publish date to the date I wanted.
3. I created an RSS feed of these posts through Drupal.
4. I linked the newly created RSS feed to IFTTT.
5. Created an IFTTT recipe to post the text from the RSS feed to Facebook/Twitter/etc.

It wasn't the best solution, but it worked.  I was really trying to do this without having to rely on a third-party such as IFTTT, but never really figured out a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are various tools that let you define Facebook and Twitter posts in advance, to be published at a specified date and time in the future. Why not use one of those instead of writing your own?

A quick search for "scheduled twitter post" uncovered [Later Bro](http://laterbro.com/), [Twuffer](http://twuffer.com/) and [twAitter](http://www.twaitter.com/) but there must be dozens to choose from.

Comment: Two reasons why... 1st was I was not wanting to have to rely on a third party service to do this.  2nd, to setup all of those future posts, like I descirbed above, is very labor intensive.  Since I already have these posts laid out in a spreadsheet, I was hoping just to convert all of those into an RSS feed or similar without having to manually setup all of those posts in a third software program.  Thank you for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for just posting on Facebook and Twitter, and not an RSS feed as well, I'd follow Matthew's suggestion. If you want an RSS feed, there is a feed for each Twitter feed.  But if you want actual RSS, you need to add something in between.  An RSS feed is just an XML file.  it's not a process.  I suggest having a file of some type (maybe RSS, or other XML, or a database table, or even a csv file with all the posts and relevant information, including date. Then a small script that runs as a chron job (or IFTTT if it supports date as trigger and running a script as the "then" part) that pulls the day's feed and updates the actual RSS feed.  Pretty simple.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  If you see below, you'll see my full process that I used to complete this.